# Is there a way to figure out in which quad I am in fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, matrix, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

In my openGL project I draw a lot of quads (composed from 2 triangles) - for sake of example let's say quad 0,1,2 and 3. I process them in single pass. I do transform them with projection view matrix in Vertex shader.

Is there then any way in Fragment shader to tell in which quad (0,1,2,3) I am currently drawing the pixel?

Comment: Have you considered using the [provoking vertex](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Provoking_vertex) id for this?

Comment: No I haven't! Reading.

Comment: @DMGregory I have read it trough now x times, but do not understand how this solves my particular problem. Maybe you can try give an answer with some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done this myself, but something in this vein should work:

Define a varying variable to send the vertex ID from the vertex shader to the fragment shader. Use the `flat` attribute so that it's not interpolated between vertices — instead the value from the provoking vertex will be used for all fragments in the triangle.

```
flat out int vId;
shader void main() { 
    vId = gl_VertexID;
}
```

Then in your fragment shader you can read this ID and divide it down (rounding down) to identify the quad:

```
flat in int vId;
void main() {
    int quadId = vId/4;
    // TODO: do something with quadId
}
```

Assuming your first quad is made up of vertices 0-3 in your buffer, this will round down to 0 for all fragments in that quad. If your next quad is made up of vertices 4-7, this will round down to 1 for those fragments, and so on.

Comment: Will try this ASAP and give feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a vertex attribute per quad, and send that as a varying to your fragment shader.